# Does the facebook uri scheme no longer work on iOS6?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6

I used `fb://publish/?text=` to publish from my app in iOS to Facebook but this doesn't work anymore with the Facebook app update to version 5.0 (not iOS6 update). Does anyone know how to publish with new app? Are there another URI schemes that can be used?

I don't want to use any native integration, just a link...

Comment: Nope, none of the old schemes work. It's possible that there just was a re-design, and some of that code that we were so dependent on was taken out, but I don't know.

Comment: schemes like fb://profile still works

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this will be helpful to you.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [params setObject:str forKey:@"message"];

    [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"stream.publish" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

But for this you must have assigned publish permission.